# Не работет google maps во время релиза

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Не работают гугл карты во время релиза, не знаю, что делать, подскажите, пожалуйста

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bellkrossy.subwaykiev10">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        <activity
            android:name="com.bellkrossy.subwaykiev10.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.bellkrossy.subwaykiev10.RedActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.bellkrossy.subwaykiev10.RedActivityList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.bellkrossy.subwaykiev10.BlueActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.bellkrossy.subwaykiev10.BlueActivityList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.bellkrossy.subwaykiev10.GreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.bellkrossy.subwaykiev10.GreenActivityList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <!-- <uses-library android:name="array"></uses-library> -->
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.bellkrossy.subwaykiev10.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

google_maps_api(debug)

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
        AIzaSyDykdKaezq8cGyReuh_ExSf71sIHYu66k
    </string>
```

google_maps_api(release)

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
        AIzaSyDykdKaezq8cGyReuh_ExSf71sIHYu66k
    </string>
```

Comment: Не надо менять вопрос. Задавайте новый

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо проверить есть ли в настройках в консоли гугла  SHA-1 отпечатки и дебажного и релизного ключа

Comment: SHA-1 есть, а что за отпечатки дебажного и релизного ключа?

Comment: Для выкладывания в маркет вам будет нужен релизый ключ. Его надо самостоятельно создать. И его отпечаток также добавить в консоль гугла

Comment: и вместо обычного ЩА-1(который в гугл картах прописан в оф документации) ключа нужно добавить отпечаток релизного ключа? и потом в манифест его закинуть?

Comment: Посмотрите ещё раз в документацию - вам надо добавить отпечатки всех ваших ключей. Дебажного и релизного. Возможно, вы используете SHA-1 из гуглового примера. Куда добавлять не помню, в браузере, вроде, надо в консоли для разработчиков это добавлять.